# equation in Tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations

I have been trying to write this equation in tikz but had no luck. [image]

Any ideas?

Comment: please, show us, what you try so far. and tell, where you stuck!

Comment: And please consider accepting some of your old answers or at least leave a commant to tell why these are no good for your request.

Comment: I did try to adjust the previous answer but when I try to use it more than once in the same document it doesn't work.

Comment: Basically it's a good idea to rephrase your question rather than asking a new one in your case. The answers **are** working, you could've commented on them and edited the old questions. And one more thing: as @koleygr mentioned, please consider accepting answers to your old questions if they helped you. This marks them as solved (so nobody has to look into it again, just to find working answers) and you also gain some reputation, as well as the user who answered.

Comment: How have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can really just copy my previous answer and slightly modify it to obtain

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,braket,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \Braket{a_{\tikzmark{1-1}i\tikzmark{1-2}}|\Phi}
 ~=~
 \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\Braket{
 a_{\tikzmark{2-1}i\tikzmark{2-2}}\,\hat{x}\,
 a_{\tikzmark{3-1}j\tikzmark{3-2}}}\Braket{
 a_{\tikzmark{4-1}j\tikzmark{4-2}}|
 \Psi}\;.
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{ \draw[latex-,shorten <=1pt] ($(pic cs:\X-1)!0.5!(pic cs:\X-2)$) 
 -- ++ (0,-1) node[below]{$\scriptstyle i$};}
\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt] 
 ($(pic cs:3-1)!0.5!(pic cs:3-2)$) 
 -- ++ (0,-.5) -| ($(pic cs:4-1)!0.5!(pic cs:4-2)$)
 node[pos=0.25,below]{$\scriptstyle jj$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is absolutely no new thing that is needed.

**ADDENDUM**: If you are using these tricks in several equations, you need, as nox pointed out, to make the names of the tikzmarks unique. For instance, I can combine this with my previous answer by prepending `A` and `B` to the tikzmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,braket,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \phi_{\tikzmark{A1-1}1\tikzmark{A1-2}}
 ~=~x_{\tikzmark{A2-1}1\tikzmark{A2-2}1\tikzmark{A2-3}}\,
 \psi_{\tikzmark{A3-1}1\tikzmark{A3-2}}+
 x_{\tikzmark{A4-1}1\tikzmark{A4-2}2\tikzmark{A4-3}}\,
 \psi_{\tikzmark{A5-1}2\tikzmark{A5-2}}\;.
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \X in {1,2,4}
{ \draw[latex-,shorten <=1pt] ($(pic cs:A\X-1)!0.5!(pic cs:A\X-2)$) 
 -- ++ (0,-1) node[below]{$\scriptstyle1$};}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+1)},count=\Z]in {2,4}
{\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt] 
 ($(pic cs:A\X-2)!0.5!(pic cs:A\X-3)$) 
 -- ++ (0,-.5) -| ($(pic cs:A\Y-1)!0.5!(pic cs:A\Y-2)$) 
 node[below,pos=0.25]{$\scriptstyle\Z\Z$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{equation}
 \Braket{a_{\tikzmark{B1-1}i\tikzmark{B1-2}}|\Phi}
 ~=~
 \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\Braket{
 a_{\tikzmark{B2-1}i\tikzmark{B2-2}}\,\hat{x}\,
 a_{\tikzmark{B3-1}j\tikzmark{B3-2}}}\Braket{
 a_{\tikzmark{B4-1}j\tikzmark{B4-2}}|
 \Psi}\;.
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{ \draw[latex-,shorten <=1pt] ($(pic cs:B\X-1)!0.5!(pic cs:B\X-2)$) 
 -- ++ (0,-1) node[below]{$\scriptstyle i$};}
\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt] 
 ($(pic cs:B3-1)!0.5!(pic cs:B3-2)$) 
 -- ++ (0,-.5) -| ($(pic cs:B4-1)!0.5!(pic cs:B4-2)$)
 node[pos=0.25,below]{$\scriptstyle jj$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could mention the `\nolimits` command for the sum

Comment: @nox Thanks! I personally like this notation better and let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: I agree, I prefer it as well. I just thought if a hand-written equation is using it... Let's see if OP says something at all ;-)

Comment: the problem is that if I try to use this script more than once in the same document it doesn't work.

Comment: @Evan Name the tikzmarks accordingly (uniquely!) and it should work. Else, what you're trying to do is similar to a document using the same labels more than once

Comment: @Evan It does work. You only need to give the marks different names. For instance, if you replace all `\tikzmark{` here by `\tikzmark{A` and all `(pic cs:` by `(pic cs:A` it will happily coexist with the code from my previous answer. As nox pointed out, the marks need to have unique names. Notice that I already used braket in my previous answer, where it was not used, but my [crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) did not tell me that you want to put a second marked equation on the same page. ;-)

Comment: @Evan I added an explicit example that combines the previous and current answers.

Comment: @marmot Thank you I didn't realise I had to rename them. The only change I had to add was to change the \Braket to a \langle and \rangle respectively. Otherwise it worked perfectly.

Comment: In order to have the desired result near page breaks, and always the default space, one could move the `tikzpicture` environment at the end of (into) the equation environment and add, eg., `\rule[-40pt]{0pt}{0pt}` or `\rule[-9ex]{0pt}{0pt}` afterwards. You could, alternatively, measure the actual height of the picture and use that.